# Dynamically create an object in mootools or javascript

Tags: javascript, object, mootools

I am not sure if I am using the correct terms for what I am trying to do so please excuse that.

Mootools More has an [Fx.Elements](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Elements) class that allows you to tween a collection of elements. The [`set`](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Elements#Fx-Elements%3aset) method of the class only accepts an object and allows me to set the original values, however I am not sure how many elements I'll be having to tween as the HTML will be generated dynamically.

Here is my theory of what I want to do:

```
var n = $$('.element').length; // 5
var myObj = {};
var value = 0;
var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    myObj = {
      i: { property : value }
    }                        
}

console.log(myObj);

//    What I get:
//    Object { i : { property: 0 } }

//    What I would like:
//    Object { 
//      0 : { property : 0 
//      },
//      1 : { property : 0 
//      },
//      2 : { property : 0 
//      },
//      3 : { property : 0 
//      },
//      4 : { property : 0 
//      }
//    }
```

The above, obviously, only sets the `i` property of the object 5 times. I need `i` to iterate upwards.

I hope I have explained better than I think I have!

Comment: Your code is leaking a global `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the object literal syntax keys are always treated as strings - even without quotes. Besides that, you overwrite the whole object everytime.

This code does what you want. Note that I changed it to `i < n` since you'll get `i = 5` in the last loop which does not fit to the example you posted.

```
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    myObj[i] = {
        property: value
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, it works. :) I am sure I tried this before and just kept getting an array.

Comment: `myObj = []` gives you an array, `myObj = {}` an object.

Comment: Fx.Elements expects an object as argument, not an array, the iterator will be `Object.each` and that may work for Array as it inherits/extends Object but it's not guaranteed to work. eg, Array has a `.length` property as well as stuff on the proto.